# How to initialize a variable from a class method binding C++ with Swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to bind some C++ code to python thanks to swig.
In my C++ code, I initialize some important variables via class methods.
However, this kind of initialization seems to create some troubles to swig which returns `Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.`

Below is a very simple example extracted from swig documentation, where I only add this kind of initialization from a method.
This example is made of 3 files (`my_class.hpp` ; `my_class.cpp` ; `py_myclass.i`).

my_class.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass {
    public:
    float getSqr();
    float getSqr(float _v);
    
    private:
    float value=2.;
};

float toto=MyClass().getSqr(3.);     // the only line I added !

#endif
```

my_class.cpp

```cpp
#include "my_class.hpp"

float MyClass::getSqr() {
    return getSqr(value);
}

float MyClass::getSqr(float value) {
    return value*value;
}
```

py_myclass.i

```
%module py_myclass

%{
#include "my_class.hpp"
%}

%include "my_class.hpp"
```

So, the only modification I made from swig documentation was to add the initialization line `float toto=MyClass().getSqr(3.);`.
I tried to play around a bit with it, but I always get the syntax error.

From these files, I execute swig to create wrappers.
I do it with the command line:

```
swig -python -c++ -o py_myclass_wrap.cpp py_myclass.i
```

which yields me the following error:

```
py_myclass.i:13: Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.
```

So, is there a way to accomplish this kind of initialization with swig ?

I also tried to add the line `%ignore toto;` before the last `%include "my_class.hpp"` in the file `py_myclass.i`, but it seems that the ignoring was ignored itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG's C++ parser doesn't support that initialization syntax, it seems.

Instead, in the header use:

```cpp
extern float toto;
```

In the .cpp file initialize it:

```cpp
float toto=MyClass().getSqr(3.);
```

Then SWIG will only see the extern declaration since it only parses the .hpp file.  Here's a run of the result:

```py
>>> import py_myclass
>>> py_myclass.cvar.toto
9.0
>>> c=py_myclass.MyClass()
>>> c.getSqr()
4.0
>>> c.getSqr(9)
81.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. Unfortunately, in my real problem, I have only .hpp without .cpp. Therefore, your solution is not applicable in such situations. Any chance you have something for such situations ? Maybe using preprocessor macros ?

Comment: @R.N `#ifdef SWIG` use the extern, else the actual line.